# How to find data transfer rates for different connections in iPhone?

Tags: iphone

i'm trying to find the API's for getting the data transfer rates for different connections like GPS, GPRS, 3G,4G and wifi. I searched in the Reachability, but couldn't find anything.
Was i looking at the wrong place? Please help me.. Thanks in advance.

vish.

Comment: I'm not going to make this an official answer, but an iPhone application should not care how it's connected to the Internet, only that it **IS** connected to the Internet. I'd be surprised if Apple allowed developers to get at the raw metrics of the various connections to the network from the OS layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no (public) APIs for this. The best thing you can do is to set up a simple UDP based echo service on a server and measure the speed of the actual connection by averaging the turnover time of your packets. Of course this will tell you the connection speed to a particular server and not the connection of your device, but it is still better then nothing.